# Block all windows system outgoing internet connections but allow LAN on Private and VPN on Public

Tags: windows, privacy, firewalls, ip, lan

I have several windows PC connected to my mikrotik. I use basic features: file sharing, playing games with friends on home LAN and want to connect internet only through VPN (openVPN client).
But I am paranoid anonymity privacy researcher. I've spent a lot of time preparing a personal privacy-focused build of Windows. Many settings, policies, cut out spy components such as cortana, defender, etc... Now I want to learn how to manage traffic and prevent IP leaks.

I set up windows firewall to block all inbound and outbound connections. I tested a lot - the default firewall rules trying to understand which ones are needed for what and leave the minimum necessary for functioning my LAN. I had to leave File and Printer Sharing, Network Discovery, DHCP and DNS. But I'm not satisfied with it. Windows with its system processes such as svhost can establish connections on its on (I guess). For example, I tried to block not enabled default rules and enable them. This disrupted the functioning of LAN communications. I had to leave a significant part of these rules inactive. I read there are hidden hardening rules in the system.

First of all I want to know is it possible to be sure that windows itself can't do its own outgoing internet connections without permission? And how can I archive this?

Second. I'm trying to conditionally divide the network into two segments and use the built-in windows division to Private and Public. **Private for LAN communications without internet access and Public for VPN internet connections**. **I want no one application or system application to be able to disclose my IP address to any remote server while I am not connected to VPN**.

Now I have this setup. Ethernet adapter network set to Private, VPN virtual adapter network set to Public. If I want to allow Internet access for an application, I add an allow rule for it with a profile Public. But I cannot be sure that the system (system applications) does not communicate with remote servers via ethernet adapter (or Private profile)

I wouldn't like to use third party software. I'm interested in solving these problems first of all with built-in windows firewall, and secondly with mikrotik firewall. And only thirdly, use third-party software, only if necessary and it is open source.

I am looking towards the following things:

- Firewall rule setting - Interface types (Local Area Network, Remote
  access, Wireless)
- Local subnet ip range
- Custom subnet ip ranges
- Maybe something else

But I lack experience and knowledge, hope for your help
[image]

Comment: Some VPN provider software offers a kill switch which disables internet communication when the VPN is not running. Maybe look into how they do it but iirc this will also disable LAN communication. When using a separate firewall (like on the router) it is imho easier to block traffic than on Windows itself. When using Windows you need to dump potential outgoing traffic and block/kill the program or service causing it.

Comment: It's normal that lan doesn't work when vpn is enabled. That's the way it should be. 
I don't know how to analyze their software.
I would like to know how exactly I can block traffic.
I can't kill system processes like dns-client, dhcp (svhost). I can only edit firewall rules regarding these services so that the traffic works locally, but does not work to the outside world. But in fact this is my question, I don't know how to do it. Use interface types or ip range or something else?
And what rules if we speak about router?

Comment: imho Windows is rather unfriendly regarding blocking and Windows updates in the past changed rules. Dunno if this is still the case: https://superuser.com/questions/1091439/how-to-prevent-windows-update-from-re-enabling-firewall-rules When blocking on the router you could by default block everything coming from Windows and only allow connections to the VPN.

Comment: @secfren I know many about Windows, I know who they are and what they do. I hate them for many things. This is a war on uneven ground. I can export and import the policy before updates.
Your post is somewhat helpful.
I'm ready to set up rules on the router, but I still don't have enough experience and practice to understand which specific rules to use. 
I'm also willing to use a third party open source application

Comment: I can't really comment on the Windows part. In case of the router it depends on what software is installed (OS from the manufacturer, openwrt) or if you can install your own OS. Then you need firewall rules for routing, dropping Windows traffic and only allowing VPN traffic. There are tutorials out there but it will depend on how your setup exactly looks like, the firewall software, etc.

Comment: Mikrotik has Router OS software. Firewall section looks like this
![img-firewall-filter](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LqPyMzZ6NQ4/VeT-GpmwdgI/AAAAAAAAAdA/tTZIdad3Y7k/s1600/1Firewall.jpg)
I have my rules setup made by different manuals. But I don't know how to logically separate Windows traffic from VPN, one adapter from another, one profile from another, local address range from internet address range, etc.

Comment: I am not familiar with this software but they have a forum where you could ask. Where is the VPN running? On Windows or the router? Can you install custom software on the router like some Linux/BSD?

Comment: VPN running on windows (openvpn client and its virtual adapter). Sure in the future I will try to install custom open source software on my router.
Thanks for your support

Comment: Thats why it is easier when blocking/VPN happens on the router. When it runs on Windows then Windows traffic will also go through the VPN unless you manage to block all of it.